# How to measure performance of browser extension on websites (> 100)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, performance-testing

I'm looking for tools for measuring webpage performance with certain browser(Chrome) extension installed. I would like to know things like # of requests, time to first byte, slowest call, average call, FCP, and LCP et. al..

I've used development tool that comes with the browser and extensions such as [Page load time](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=search-browser-5march&gclid=CjwKCAjw682TBhATEiwA9crl359LA7NZlU7shAq_-N_XBoEAIv8HntOyzy5kkA1cBSofRyEkx7xyihoC4rEQAvD_BwE), [Performance-Analyser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/performance-analyser/djgfmlohefpomchfabngccpbaflcahjf?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=search-browser-5march&gclid=CjwKCAjw682TBhATEiwA9crl359LA7NZlU7shAq_-N_XBoEAIv8HntOyzy5kkA1cBSofRyEkx7xyihoC4rEQAvD_BwE).

I'm look for some method/tool that can load pages one by one from a list and be able to download the results, so I can test many webpages and batch process the results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any suitable browser automation framework i.e. [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) which is some form a de-facto [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/)

Check out [6 Easy Steps to Testing Your Chrome Extension With Selenium](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium) for example

There is also [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) tool which can also be considered and executed [from shell scripts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse#cli) or [programmatically](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md#using-programmatically), however it's more web-oriented hence not all metrics will be applicable so you might get a lot of false-negative results.

Comment: I tried Lighthouse, but it doesn't seem that the extension I loaded unpacked was running when I use `lighthouse https://example.com --disable-device-emulation --chrome-flags="--user-agent=edge --window-size=360,640"`